# Devise User testing with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I've integrated Devise with my RoR app and am now trying to test my Controllers, specifically the one that routes me to my `root_url`.

I've used this HOWTO on Devise's page to setup my admin/user Factories, but there is an additional component that is part of my user signup process, which is creating a `Company`.

So:

`User`: `has_one :company`

`Company`: `has_many :users`

The flow for a new user looks like this:

1. User signs up
2. User confirms account (via email) and is redirected to the login page
3. User logs in
4. User fills out `Company` information and submits
5. User is then redirected to `Pages#home` (which is my `root_url`)

Using Devise's HOWTO, I created a `ControllerHelpers` file within `Support`:

```
module ControllerHelpers
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      user.confirm # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

I suspect there is something wrong with my `User Factory` since it doesn't seem like a `Company` is being created, but I'm so new to RSpec, I'm unsure.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "Test"
    last_name "User"
    full_name "Test User"
    email "test@user.com"
    phone_number "111-222-3333"
    terms_accepted true
    time_zone "Central Time (US & Canada)"
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    confirmed_at Date.today
    association :company
  end
end
```

And I have a `company.rb` factory as well:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :company do
    id 1
    name "ACME Test"
    address_1 "123 Shady Lane."
    address_2 "Suite 400"
    city "Testville"
    state "Test"
    zip_code "12345"
    has_payment_plan false
    stripe_id "cus_34d434343e4e3e3"
    locked false
  end
end
```

My `pages_controller_spec.rb` is simple at this point:

require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe PagesController, :type => :controller do

  describe "User: GET #home" do
    login_user

    it "signs in the user" do
      expect(response).to render_template(:home)
    end
  end
end
```

This results in the following RSpec error:

```
1) PagesController User: GET #home signs in the user
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:home)
   expecting <"home"> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/companies/new>
 # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So, it's not even doing the `render_template` portion of my test?

**UPDATE: Added Home Controller**

`controllers/pages_controller#home`

```
def home
    if current_user && current_user.company
      verify_subscription
      get_company_and_locations
      get_network_hosts
      get_network_hosts_at_risk
      @network_hosts_snip = @network_hosts_at_risk.sort_by{ |h| -h.security_percentage }.first(5)
      get_company_issues
      @issues = @issues.sort_by{ |i| -i.cvss_score }.first(5)
      @deferred_issues = @company.deferred_issues.last(5)
      @deferred_hosts = @company.deferred_hosts.last(5)
    else
      redirect_to new_company_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: It's not the answer for your main question but still... Your company is created but isn't persisted to DB. It's what `strategy: :build` goes for. So to create your company and persist it to DB replace `association :company, strategy: :build` with just `company`. However I'll try to find the answer on the main question. Could you add the `home` action of the controller you're trying to test?

Comment: @VAD Just added the pages#home controller method

Comment: Ok, turns out that this probably is the answer on your main question. Now with corrections in the `user` factory which I suggested you must have `current_user` and it's `company` created so your `home` action won't go on `redirect_to` and will perform default `render` instead. And nothing else should prevent your test from passing. Try it out and if it pass I'll add my previous comment as an answer.

Comment: @VAD Sorry, I'm pretty new to 'testing' in general, so I'm not completely understanding what we've done here.  Also, still not working...

Comment: We just set up things for your user's association object `company` persisting into DB instead of just creating in memory. Is the error appears now the same as before?

Comment: No, I've updated the code and failure.  This part of the code is related to my `subscription` now.  So I guess I need to make an association for that within my company factory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134409/discussion-between-vad-and-godzilla74).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found out together in the chat... Your `company` was created but wasn't persisted to DB. It's because you had `strategy: :build` in your factory.

`strategy: :build` means that your association object will be created but won't be persisted to DB. To persist it you should use `strategy: :create`. Or in your use case you can replace `association :company, strategy: :build` with just `company`. FactoryGirl is smart enough to recognize it as an association which must be created and persisted.

And you need to set up FactoryGirl association between `company` and `subscription` the same way.